# XML version of a unity config?

Tags: wcf, unity-container

I'm trying to convert a sample I found to an XML config..

If this is what I'd do in code;

```
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IServiceProxy<ITestService>, ServiceProxy<ITestService, TestServiceClient>>();
```

What do I do in XML? I'm trying this, but I'm missing something;

```
 <unity>
    <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="IServiceProxy" type="WCF.IServiceProxy, WCF" />
    <typeAlias alias="ITestService"type="Interfaces.ITestService, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="IServiceProxy[ITestService],ServiceProxy[ITestService,TestServiceClient]]" />
    </typeAliases>
    <containers>
    <container name="servicesContainer">
    <type type="IServiceProxy" mapTo="ServiceProxy" />
    <type type="ITestService" mapTo="TestService" />
    </container>
    </containers>
</unity>
```

Comment: Presumably you're seeing an error message or some unexpected behavior.  Can you please provide more details?  Also, for what it's worth, I avoid using Unity's XML config as it has brought me nothing but pain.  I'd much rather have the strong typing provided by the fluent configuration.

Comment: no error, I just don't get a service client when i do a resolve on TestService or ITestService

Comment: Do you have multiple implementations (other than for tests)? If not, just use the fluent code syntax. You can rebuild to run your tests. XML makes things harder, not easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aliases are completely fubared in your example. You can't use the square bracket syntax in aliases for one, you must use CLR type syntax. In the last alias, you just give an alias which is a big long string but you never specify the type. You also never supply the ServiceProxy alias, so that name just doesn't exist and can't be found.

Assuming you're using Unity 2.0, and you've added the appropriate <namespace> and <assembly> nodes in the XML to point to your assemblies, this should work:

```
<unity>
  <namespace name="WhateverYourNamespaceIs" />
  <assembly name="AndWhateverAssembliesAre" />
  <container name="servicesContainer">
    <register type="IServiceProxy[ITestService]" mapTo="ServiceProxy[ITestService, TestServiceClient]" />
  </container>
</unity>
```

Answer (score 2):

I only know Unity 2.0 syntax, and this isn't it. For example the `type` nodes should be `register`, and the `containers` node was never supported in any version of Unity. Is it possible you are looking at old/poor documentation?

Make sure you are using Unity 2.0. Then start reading the [Using Design-Time Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx)

Just scanning your xml some of the other issues:

1. There's no alias defined for ServiceProxy or TestService.
2. IServiceProxy[] alias:

   - It doesn't define a type
   - Recursive aliases are *not* supported.

[Specifying Types in the Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx#_Type_Aliases) will help you with alias syntax.